# How can I change the font size of Android Studio IDE?

Tags: android-studio

I am very new to Android studio and wanted to change the IDE font size. However, it changed automatically my font size when change it from 14 to 13 and ended up with a font size of 143. Literally, I cannot access it anymore.

Now, I deleted and re-installed Android Studio and the same problem appeared. Is there maybe a possibility in the terminal of my mac or specific installation file I can change it?

[image]

Comment: What exactly did you try to do, to change the size, which failed?

Comment: I actually just wanted to change the theme and font size of the IDE. Nothing more. But now I am stuck. The image literally shows how my screen looks when opening android studio.

Comment: You said "it changed automatically my font size when change it from 14 to 13". Thus, I was asking how you tried to "change it from 14 to 13". Knowing what you did could help readers determine what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you reinstall it uncheck where it says to use old data from the older version's folders
or go to the android studio folders and delete them after uninstalling the program
and install it again the old settings should disappear after doing this